# How can i convert my python list to another list format

Tags: python

I have a list containing three params like this:-

```
[(8L, 'Mail Opened', 'Saturday'), (4L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Saturday'), (2L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Sunday'), (8L, 'Mail Opened', 'Sunday'), (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'), (12L, 'Mail Opened', 'Monday'), (10L, 'Mail Opened', 'Tuesday'), (4L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Tuesday'), (14L, 'Mail Opened', 'Wednesday'), (6L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Wednesday'), (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Thursday'), (19L, 'Mail Opened', 'Thursday'), (28L, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday'), (1L, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday')]
```

Can i get the result like this

```
[("Saturday",8,4)],[("Sunday",8,2)]
```

Here I have combined two tuples according to the DAYNAME. I had put 'Mail Opened' value at first place and 'Mail not opened value' at second place .Also there might be a case where only one value may exist 
then the list would look like

```
[("Saturday",0,4)],[("Sunday",8,0)]
```

Please help me

Comment: The question isn't totally clear. How can you distinguish between "mail opened" and "mail not opened" in the result list?

Comment: [ x for x in l if x[1] == "Mail Opened" ] thats how i can separate my list into two parts. now when i have two lists. there should be a certain way to join them according to the DAYNAME value

Comment: Have you considered making changes directly to the code that gives you this data in the first place?

Comment: @KarlKnectel Is this data is considered as a bad data?? Your suggestion will be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `tuple` as a `dict`, using a dictionary (or a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in this case) will be more simple.
Take a look:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [(8L, 'Mail Opened', 'Saturday'), (4L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Saturday'), (2L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Sunday'), (8L, 'Mail Opened', 'Sunday'), (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'), (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'), (12L, 'Mail Opened', 'Monday'), (10L, 'Mail Opened', 'Tuesday'), (4L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Tuesday'), (14L, 'Mail Opened', 'Wednesday'), (6L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Wednesday'), (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Thursday'), (19L, 'Mail Opened', 'Thursday'), (28L, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday'), (1L, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday')]

d = {'Mail Opened': defaultdict(list), 'Mail Not Opened': defaultdict(list)}

for num,mail,day in lst:
    d[mail][day].append(num)
```

This will divide your output between 'Mail Opend' and 'Mail Not Opened'.

#### DAYNAME as key

But it seems that I got your question confused and you wanted the output divided by DAYNAME.

In this case, with a little tweaking we can revert the nesting order of the dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [(8, 'Mail Opened', 'Saturday'), (4, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Saturday'), (2, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Sunday'), (8, 'Mail Opened', 'Sunday'), (1, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'), (1, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'), (12, 'Mail Opened', 'Monday'), (10, 'Mail Opened', 'Tuesday'), (4, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Tuesday'), (14, 'Mail Opened', 'Wednesday'), (6, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Wednesday'), (1, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Thursday'), (19, 'Mail Opened', 'Thursday'), (28, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday'), (1, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday')]


days = defaultdict(lambda : {'Mail Opened': [], 'Mail Not Opened': []})

for num,mail,day in lst:
    days[day][mail].append(num)
```

That will give this kind of output:

```
for k,v in days.iteritems():
    print k, v

"""
Monday {'Mail Not Opened': [1, 1], 'Mail Opened': [12]}
Tuesday {'Mail Not Opened': [4], 'Mail Opened': [10]}
Friday {'Mail Not Opened': [], 'Mail Opened': [28, 1]}
Wednesday {'Mail Not Opened': [6], 'Mail Opened': [14]}
Thursday {'Mail Not Opened': [1], 'Mail Opened': [19]}
Sunday {'Mail Not Opened': [2], 'Mail Opened': [8]}
Saturday {'Mail Not Opened': [4], 'Mail Opened': [8]}
"""
```

This approach will handle every case in the exact same way, so if you can refactorize your code, I really suggest this one.

#### Special case:

Haunting down your comments I found one where you said that you want to 2 different output for `('Friday', 'Mail Opened', ..)`, something like:

```
[('Friday', 1L, 0), ('Friday', 28L, 0)]
```

Instead of having them chained togheter. Does this special case rreally make sense to you? Is it a requirement? If the answers are yes, please update you question.

You also said that you wont expect more than two equals DAYNAME, but in your example there are 3 `Monday`, two of them look alike, so maybe is a typo (if it is, please update your question).
But if this is a typo are you sure the double Friday entry is not a typo?

Anyway, **removing that "extra" `Monday`**, and assuming that you **really** need that kind of output (for some compatibility API reason perhaps), you can do:

```
lst = [(8, 'Mail Opened', 'Saturday'), (4, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Saturday'), (2, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Sunday'), (8, 'Mail Opened', 'Sunday'), (1, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'), (12, 'Mail Opened', 'Monday'), (10, 'Mail Opened', 'Tuesday'), (4, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Tuesday'), (14, 'Mail Opened', 'Wednesday'), (6, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Wednesday'), (1, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Thursday'), (19, 'Mail Opened', 'Thursday'), (28, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday'), (1, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday')]

pos = {'Mail Opened': 1, 'Mail Not Opened': 2}
results = []

for num,mail,day in lst:
    found = False
    for x in results:
        if day == x[0]:
            found = True
            if x[pos[mail]] == 0:
                x[pos[mail]] = num
            else:                   # this will handle your special case
                new = [day, 0, 0]
                new[pos[mail]] = num
                results.append(new)
            break

    if not found:
        new = [day, 0, 0]
        new[pos[mail]] = num
        results.append(new)
```

This will give you this output:

```
for r in results:
    print r

"""
['Saturday', 8, 4]
['Sunday', 8, 2]
['Monday', 12, 1]
['Tuesday', 10, 4]
['Wednesday', 14, 6]
['Thursday', 19, 1]
['Friday', 28, 0]
['Friday', 1, 0]
"""
```

#### Notes:

1. This last solution doesn't care how many 'Friday' (or whatever DAYNAME) entries do you have. The old entry will not be overwritten and a new one will be created.
   But beware that if you do have more than two 'Friday' your output will be logically inconsistent and pseudo-random! This is a design failure, so that's why I'm not suggesting you to use this last approach.
2. From the error you showed in a comment (on this and another answer) looks like you're shadowing the built-in `list`. Meaning that at some point in your code you do something like:

   ```
   list = # something
   ```

   Don't do that, use another name like `lst` for example.

Comment: TypeError: first argument must be callable ,This is the error i am getting.

Comment: @saunjean: I think you may have shadowed the built-in `list`. I've updated the answer, run it exactly like it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the great effort

Comment: I agree that my answer was ugly  
But your code doesn't do what he wanted  
He is expecting to see 2 entries for Friday "('Friday', 1L, 0) and ('Friday', 28L, 0)" while your code concats them both  
To handle this trivial case i resended to if-else. (My earlier edits were a bit sane)  
Plus the OP has asked to presume that there won't be more than 2 entries with the same dayname  
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2499896#2499896  
May be sometimes code that works is better than an idiomatic one that doesn't?

Comment: @Insidi0us: If the OP thanks me, how can I know that my answer does not apply to his case? **If he has further request/special case he should update his question.** Anyway I checked out this *insane* special case and I've updated my answer. Yes your earlier edits was a bit more sane, but you were counting on the order of the orignal list and I don't think that was given, that plus all that if-elif with all those indexes results in a fragile code. But I wont discuss that here, there's a [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7191/discussion-between-insidi0us-and-saun-jean) for that.

Comment: @saunjean: Insidi0us told me that my code is not applayable to you. If that's the case **I've updated my answer**, take a look!

Comment: @RikPoggi Your effort is commendable.I really never thought that you would go so deep in the question. i needed the code for hot-patch at that time, i will use your code after testing it.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Dimensions hardcoded, But does what you wanted

```
import itertools

dat = [(8L, 'Mail Opened', 'Saturday'), (4L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Saturday'),
       (2L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Sunday'), (8L, 'Mail Opened', 'Sunday'),
       (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'), (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'),
       (12L, 'Mail Opened', 'Monday'), (10L, 'Mail Opened', 'Tuesday'),
       (4L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Tuesday'), (14L, 'Mail Opened', 'Wednesday'),
       (6L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Wednesday'), (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Thursday'),
       (19L, 'Mail Opened', 'Thursday'), (28L, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday'), (1L, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday')]

solution = []
dat.sort(key=lambda t: t[2])
for day, grp in itertools.groupby(dat, key=lambda t: t[2]):
    mo, mno = 0, 0
    grp = list(grp)
    if len(grp) == 1:
        if grp[0][1] == 'Mail Opened':
            solution.append((day, rec[0], 0))
        elif grp[0][1] == 'Mail Not Opened':
            solution.append((day, 0, rec[0]))
    elif len(grp) == 2:
        if grp[0][1] == grp[1][1]:
            if grp[0][1] == 'Mail Opened':
                solution.append((day, grp[0][0], 0))
                solution.append((day, grp[1][0], 0))
            elif grp[0][1] == 'Mail Not Opened':
                solution.append((day, 0, grp[0][0]))
                solution.append((day, 0, grp[1][0]))
        else:
            if grp[0][1] == 'Mail Opened':
                solution.append((day, grp[0][0], grp[1][0]))
            elif grp[1][0] == 'Mail Not Opened':
                solution.append((day, grp[1][0], grp[0][0]))
print(solution)

"""
Solution:
[('Friday', 28L, 0), ('Friday', 1L, 0), ('Saturday', 8L, 4L), 
('Tuesday', 10L, 4L), ('Wednesday', 14L, 6L)]
"""
```

Comment: thanks for the solution it will work for most of the times but see the list in the end, there are two fridays with 'mail opened' so it skipped one friday??

Comment: [('Friday', 1L, 0), ('Monday', 12L, 1L), ('Saturday', 8L, 4L), ('Sunday', 8L, 2L), ('Thursday', 19L, 1L), ('Tuesday', 10L, 4L), ('Wednesday', 14L, 6L)] This is the solution i got but it skipped the Friday with the 28 value and "mail opened", Can we also handle that

Comment: @saunjean Should i just add the 2 values for Friday "Mail opened"?

Comment: Can't they be listed as separate values??

Comment: @saunjean You mean 2 separate entries like ('Friday', 1L, 0) and ('Friday', 28L, 0) ?

Comment: @saunjean I assumed that there won't be more than 2 tuples with same DAYNAME, Is that okay?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7191/discussion-between-insidi0us-and-saun-jean)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution that uses a single defaultdict and convert results to the required form after processing.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def convert(source):
    days = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
    for item in source:
        opened = 1
        if item[1] == 'Mail Opened':
            opened = 0
        days[item[2]][opened] = item[0]
    return days.iteritems()

source = [
    (8L, 'Mail Opened', 'Saturday'),
    (4L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Saturday'),
    (2L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Sunday'),
    (8L, 'Mail Opened', 'Sunday'),
    (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'),
    (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Monday'),
    (12L, 'Mail Opened', 'Monday'),
    (10L, 'Mail Opened', 'Tuesday'),
    (4L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Tuesday'),
    (14L, 'Mail Opened', 'Wednesday'),
    (6L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Wednesday'),
    (1L, 'Mail Not Opened', 'Thursday'),
    (19L, 'Mail Opened', 'Thursday'),
    (28L, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday'),
    (1L, 'Mail Opened', 'Friday')]

print list(convert(source))
```

Result:

```
[('Monday', [12L, 1L]),
 ('Tuesday', [10L, 4L]),
 ('Friday', [1L, 0]),
 ('Wednesday', [14L, 6L]),
 ('Thursday', [19L, 1L]), 
 ('Sunday', [8L, 2L]),
 ('Saturday', [8L, 4L])]
```

Comment: It skips multiple occurrences of DAYNAME , see Friday is appearing twice here and it is giving this error ---> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Oh, now I see why Insidi0us' answer is so bloated.